# How do we override the font family of Uno.Material styles?

Tags: uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I'm using Material styles from [Uno.Themes](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Themes) in my project.

**How can I override the default font family used in the built-in styles?**

(I'm assuming there's a way to do this without redefining the whole `ControlTemplate` of each style I use in my own project.)

Thanks!